# actionbar located beyound statusbar when use ActionbarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am using ActionbarActivity with Support library-v7-appcompat.
It is works fine almost.
But if I set `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` on AndroidManifest.xml, actionbar is located beyond statusbar when only run on Galaxy Nexus.(statusbar hide half of actionbar)

[like this image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/105111788@N06/10217443483/)

When I touch option menu icon or rotate device, actoinbar is move collect position (below statusbar).
If remove `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` from AndroidManifest.xml, actionbar is located collect positioon.
But if so, some device (eg. HTC butterfly, Galaxy Nexus) shows menu indicator icon on bottom of window.
I don't need menu indicator icon.
Is there any soluction ?

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
```

Comment: I would recommend that you upload some screenshots somewhere and link to them to illustrate the "beyond statusbar" part. With respect to the "menu button of shame", set `android:targetSdkVersion` to be 14 or higher.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of it?

Comment: I'm sorry for no screenshot.
I added screenshot and manifest settings